# What is primitive divergence?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, terminology, renormalization, regularization

1. As in the title, what is [primitive divergence](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=primitive+divergence)? 
   How is it distinguished from normal divergence?
2. As a followup, what is a primitive divergent graph in a theory? 
   Some simple examples?

Comment: Can you provide a reference that uses the term *primitive divergence*?

Comment: The Google search Qmechanic has edited in has [this book as its top result](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=9xwARECyKyIC&pg=PA381&lpg=PA381&dq=%22primitive+divergence%22&source=bl&ots=qonzh0r8Re&sig=E4vYN5mMH4c7HdEyXj6VXVcJyfc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1_52VZeAK4arsAG3s4PABg&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22primitive%20divergence%22&f=false) and at a quick read the book seems to answer your questions. Can you read through the relevant parts of the book and update your question to explain exactly what you don't understand.

Comment: I got it now. I was searching without the "" and that book is not really in the results without the apices.. should I answer my own question then?